# GWT SE friendly application

Tags: gwt, seo

How can I develop 'Search Engine Friendly' web app in GWT? Take an example of StackOverflow itself, it's a web app and should be SEO friendly allowing users to search from search engines. If someone wants to develop same app in GWT. How can one make it SEO friendly?

GWT contains a single HTML file. How can we allow its inner content to be visible in SE?

Any suggestion or comment, will really help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you got anything more for SEO? If yes please list here, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it crawlable ... this could be helpful http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Comment: Hi, i've tried this approach, however I'm stuck at one part. I know i need to creat a Servlet Filter mapped to the root url, right? so what i do is put the mapping to /*  . However, it does not work. The filter is not being called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

As someone who has done this before, I want to warn you.  If you are going to do a small application and want to be searched by google, great.  http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ will work.  If you want to build a tool that includes bing, then you will be out of luck.  You are better off breaking up your navigation with HTML and embedding your GWT in one of the pages.

Until all search engines can handle this, you will spend precious resources trying to work redirection and carefully reviewing search engine results.

Answer (score 0):

When building an SPA, you don't have to do anything specific for Google anymore. Google's AJAX crawling scheme has been [deprecated been Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

You just have to make sure your website serves your users well, and that it is convenient to use. Google will crawl it in a way relatively close to your user experience.

Should you want to do more, however, you can use [Prerender](https://prerender.io/). I would recommend checking that article:

- https://moz.com/blog/optimizing-angularjs-single-page-applications-googlebot-crawlers