# Google Not Indexing AJAX URLs

Tags: ajax, gwt, search-engine, web-crawler, google-search

I have submitted a sitemap for my AJAX web application to Google via their Webmaster Tools.  The submitted URLs are of the form:

- `http://www.mysite.com/#!myscreen;id=object-id`
- `http://www.mysite.com/#!myotherscreen;id=another-id`

However, even though more than a week has passed since sitemap submission, Google has not indexed the URLs.  Google states that the sitemap has been processed, states that 60 URLs have been detected, states that no errors occurred, but does not index any of the URLs.

I have already implemented the AJAX crawlability contract on the server side, where requests containing an _escaped_fragment_ are responded to with a snapshot.

Any help/info regarding why Google is not indexing the URLs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HAve you had any luck with this? I have the exact same problem (I saw that my post was linked in your post on google forums)

Comment: Google started indexing about 10 days after I submitted my sitemap.  However; I currently have about 100 URLs submitted through my sitemaps, but only 9 of them have been indexed.

Answer (score 0):

See [GWT SE friendly application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445608/gwt-se-friendly-application)

Suggestions include following the guide at http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you don't need to do something specific for Google anymore, and AJAX crawling scheme has been [deprecated been Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

Just make sure that your website is easy to use for your users, and Google will be able to properly crawl it.

If you want to go the extra mile, however, you can check that article:
* https://moz.com/blog/optimizing-angularjs-single-page-applications-googlebot-crawlers